# Apparent contradiction in properties of the pullback of forms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I think this question is better illustrated with an example.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\theta=xydx+y^2dy\ \in\Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

We know that $f^*:\Omega(\mathbb{R}^2)\rightarrow\Omega(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is linear and $f^*(\omega\wedge\alpha)=f^*(\omega)\wedge f^*(\alpha)$.
 Using linearity: $f^*\theta=xyf^*dx+y^2f^*dy\ $. Using the second property ($xy$ and $y^2$ are 0-forms): $f^*\theta=f^*xy\wedge f^*dx+f^*y^2\wedge f^*dy\ $

So I get two different things. What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention! The pull-back is linear over $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$ if you work with complex objects), but not over $\mathcal C ^\infty (M, \Bbb R)$ (or $\mathcal C ^\infty (M, \Bbb R)$). In other words, you may take numbers out of $f^*$, but not functions!

Your first approach is mistaken because $f^* (xy \ \Bbb dx) = f^*(xy) \ f^* (\Bbb dx) = [(xy) \circ f] \ \Bbb d (x \circ f)$.

Comment: I thought it was linear over the ring underlying $\Omega(U)$ (which is $C^\infty(U)$)! Ok, now it makes sense.

Comment: @Simoes: If things were as you said, then think of what would happen on $0$-forms, i.e. functions: you would have $f^* (\phi) = \phi f^* (1) = \phi \cdot (1 \circ f) = \phi$, clearly absurd. Furthermore, if $f : M \to N$, then $f^* : \Omega(N) \to \Omega(M)$, so when (incorrectly) writing $f^* (\phi \omega) = \phi f^* (\omega)$ you would have a problem with the arguments, because $\phi$ is a function on $N$ while $f^* (\omega)$ is a form on $M$, so how would you multiply them?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you have a 1-form field: at each point of $\mathbb R^3$ you may evaluate to obtain a 1-form. And to evaluate the coefficients (which are functions on the domain) you must first precompose $f$